# timeout and select() not working as expected

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to communicate with a server using an rcon protocol to take control over a gamesever. So far I was using an exisiting C# library for this but this library is sometimes quite buggy and therefore I'm was writing my own application in C++ so that I'm able to use it both on windows and on my linux server.

So far this worked out pretty well but now I'm running into problems when I try to set a timeout using select() to find out if the server still started and responding to my commands. During the first run of the application select() always returns the right value, but after closing and running it again, results get weird.

My code pretty much looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// Socket Includes
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

// Other Includes
#include "main.h"
#include "crc32.h"

int main() {

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int mysocket, slen = sizeof(server);
    char buffer[2048];


    if ((mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        printf("error creating socket");

    memset((char *) &server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    server.sin_port = htons(1234);

    if(connect(mysocket, (sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        printf("error connecting the socket");

    bool isConnected = false;
    /*
    Creating the Packet to send, cut to save some space
    */
    sendto(mysocket, loginPacket.c_str(), loginPacket.length(), 0, (sockaddr *) &server, slen);

    while(1) {

        // clearing the buffer
        bzero(buffer, 2048);

        // Timeout Settings
        int selectSize = 0;
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        fd_set fds;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(mysocket, &fds);

        selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
        std::cout << "Size is: " selectSize << std::endl; // just for testing :)

        if (selectSize == 1) {
            int recvLength = recvfrom(mysocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr *) &server, (socklen_t*) &slen);
            if (buffer[7] == 0x00) {
                if (buffer[8] == 0x01) {
                    //password correct
                    isConnected = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (buffer[8] == 0x00) {
                    //password wrong, do sth.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // tests
    sayHello();
    close(mysocket);
    return 0;
}
```

When I start the script for the first time and the server is not started, everything works as expected, after 5 seconds selectSize returns the value 0. It loops further on until I start the the server, then it will return value 1 and break the while loop. Afterwards I quit the application, turn off the server and start the script again. Instead of return value 0 after 5 seconds, it immediately returns value 1 (even though the server is offline and there's not packet to receive) and then after 5 seconds it will return value 0. Running the same script (with some adjustments) on windows gave me pretty much the same result, but selectSize pretty much always returned 1, even though the server was offline and the value should have been 0. I read tons of sites about using select() the right way but none of them helped me so far as select() is not returning reliable results after quitting and restarting the application.

P.S.: There was some confusing information about how to use select() the right way, I used pretty much every solution provided on the internet like:

```
selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
selectSize = select(0, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
selectSize = select(1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);
```

But none of them gave me a reliable result.

Comment: It might have something to do with you using `connect` on a connection-less protocol. Wh'en using UDP you usually do not "connect" to servers, you instead *bind* the socket to a local interface and port, and then send/receive data without having a connection.

Comment: Also, if you have some errors anywhere, you just print a simple message (you should really check `errno` to see what's wrong) and the just continue with the program. Often when you receive socket errors they are of a nature that you can't just continue.

Comment: Thanks for your information in the first post, I'll have a look into it. Regarding your second post this was just a quick test last night to see if running this script in linux environment gives me reliable select() result :P

Comment: @JoachimPilebog There is indeed such an operation as connectin a UDP socket, and it would not cause this problem. See *man connect*.

Comment: What does FD_ISSET(mySocket, &fds) return?

Comment: For UDP, the code is really not sensible. The `connect` does nothing but set the dest addr -- it does not wait for any kind of response from the server as it would in TCP. Hence, calling `sendto` immediately after the `connect` call doesn't guarantee that a packet will be received. If the server might not be running yet, and you intend for it to get the "`loginPacket`", you should put the `sendto` inside the loop. (Also, you needn't use `sendto` after `connect` as the latter will already have established the dest addr. If different, `sendto` will override [on linux at least].)

Comment: BTW, the correct `select` call is the one you're using (highest numbered file descriptor + 1): `selectSize = select(mysocket + 1, &fds, 0, 0, &timeout);`

Comment: Calling `connect()` on a UDP socket allows 1) use of `send()` and `recv()` instead of `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`, 2) `recv()` to ignore packets that were not sent from the "connected" peer, and 3) `send()` and `recv()` to report errors if ICMP responses indicate the remote host is not reachable.

Comment: Thanks for all your advices. Meanwhile I tweaked my code a little and removed the connect() function, now it seems to work as desired, I had no more false positives. Don't know why it works now, as I'm pretty sure that I tried that approach before and it didn't work, but now it works.